# Angular A-Z reverse sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm sure there must be a simple solution right in front of my face for this one but damned if I can find it.

I sort a large ng-repeat by various sort options, so I pass an array of sort options. The user can also choose how the data is sorted.

I can sort by A-Z fine, but for some reason the reverse of that (Z-A) isn't working as expected.

Here's a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tk39P/4/

All I'm doing is the same as I've used in lots of other sorting functionality across other Angular apps:

```
return -result.whatever;
```

So, what have I done wrong? :)
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code bit according to this
$scope.orderBy = 'price-low-high';
        $scope.predicate='price';
        $scope.reverse=true;

```
    $scope.orderByOptions = function (result) {
        if ($scope.orderBy == 'price-high-low') {
            $scope.predicate='price';
            $scope.reverse=false;

        }
        else if ($scope.orderBy == 'letter-az') {
            $scope.predicate='letter';
            $scope.reverse=false;

        }
        else if ($scope.orderBy == 'letter-za') {
            $scope.predicate='letter';
            $scope.reverse=true;

        }
        else
        {
            $scope.predicate='price';
            $scope.reverse=true;
        }


    };
```

**HTML**
Chnage data-ng-change="orderByOptions()"

```
  <select data-ng-change="orderByOptions()" class="order-by" data-ng-model="orderBy" id="orderBy" data-ng-show="results.length > 0">
```

Check **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/Tk39P/6/)**

You can also refer to this Doc [AngularJS orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: Thank you. Away from my work at the moment so I'll try and put this in to the project

Comment: This worked, thank you. The other answer also works, and that has less $scope declarations so I"m inclined to use that. I'll try setting both as correct...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if `result.letter` is a (not empty) string,

```
-result.letter
```

is `NaN`.

Then, you can use

```
-result.letter.charCodeAt(0);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tk39P/5/)

Comment: Thank you. They won't be an empty string, and will always be a longer string. I was only using single letters as an example. I'll try this in the project tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: If strings are longer than 1 character, then my answer won't work well

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 3rd argument to `orderBy`, `reverse`. Especially for a string where `return -string` does not make sense. (If you were strictly single alphabet, single case letters you could do `return "Z".charCodeAt(0)-string.charCodeAt(index)` but it is rather ugly... Then again what if `string` is not a single letter?)

So just `$watch("orderBy")` and set a scope variable `$scope.reverse` accordingly. Use it as:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="result in results
    | orderBy: [orderByOptions, orderByPriceLowToHigh]:reverse track by $index">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C3BFf/